# Firebase iOS Authentication with an unconfirmed gmail account after Google Sign in

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-authentication, google-signin

**Scenario**:

1. A user creates a `gmail.com` email account and doesn't confirm it.
2. A user uses Google sign in button to log in. Firebase replaces his/her email accout to Google sign in account as the email hasn't been confirmed.
3. A user tries to log in with a gmail email account.

**Question**
What error should I catch to tell the user that an email has already been user with another method of authentication?

**Code**

```
func signIn(with email: String, and password: String) {
    let credential = EmailAuthProvider.credential(withEmail: email, password: password)
    Auth.auth().signIn(with: credential) { (user, error) in
        if let error = error {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
            self.delegate.hideActivityIndicatorView()
            if let errorCode = AuthErrorCode(rawValue: error._code) {
                switch errorCode {
                case .accountExistsWithDifferentCredential, .credentialAlreadyInUse:
                    self.delegate.presentAlert(title: "An account with this email already exists", message: nil)
                case .userNotFound, .wrongPassword, .invalidEmail:
                    self.delegate.presentAlert(title: "Unable to Sign In", message: "Either email or password is incorrect.")
                default:
                    self.delegate.presentAlert(title: "Something went wrong, please try again later.", message: nil)
                    return
                }
            }
        }
        print("Successful Email Sign In.")
        self.delegate.hideActivityIndicatorView()
    }
}
```